# WPF DataGrid: How to discriminate between the 2 calls to event handler dataGrid_CurrentCellChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

For some reason, the CurrentCellChanged() event handler is triggered twice:

(a) When the user clicks in a cell. I would like to ignore that one.

(b) When the user has edited the cell content. This is the one I want to catch.

How can I tell the two calls apart?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is the `CellEditEnding` event instead.

See more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.celleditending(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I have been experimenting *a lot* with both event handlers and decided to use the `CellEditEnding` event for the sole purpose of saving the row being edited. Next, the `CurrentCellChanged` is called which does the actual work. I need to refresh the visual grid and that cannot be done in the first one.

Comment: Couldn't you just simply add a Boolean flag indicating whether not the cell has just changed? for example, set the flag to true inside the CellEditEnding event and then check whether it is true inside the CurrentCellChanged event, if it's true, refresh then set it back to false

Comment: That is what I have been doing, Moncada. I would just prefer a more robust approach with all those threads going on.